# footer not getting at the bottom

Tags: html, css

```
My CSS CODE

footer {
        background-color: #242424;
        bottom: 0;
        clear: both;
        color: #727272;
        height: 210px;
        left: 0;
        line-height: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

My HTML CODE

```
 <footer></footer>
```

This is my [site](http://www.doers.lk/)

You can see the footer bar on the middle.why is that i used correct CSS for that ??? any help would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: relative` to show footer under main body content or `position: fixed` to stick it at the bottom of your page.

Answer (score 1):

Use position: relative instead  position: absolute;

I see u used  min-height: 2000px; .Please used it as the your content go through that point

```
 body {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-height: 2000px;
        width: 980px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
min-height: 2000px;
```

from body